# Java - subclass validation design pattern

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns

I am having a base class `C` with fields `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

`C1` extends `C` and is having an extra field, `T`.

In the `C1` constructor, I do call the super (`C`) constructor with some hard coded values for the fields  `X`, `Y` and `Z`. Then I set `T`.

Are there any patterns to automatically validate all the fields of `C1` by doing something in the `C` constructor ? So I am trying to push the automatic validation to the base class.

Please note that calling the super constructor should be done before any statement in the `C1` constructor. I started with some abstract `validate()` method, but I am not I am on the right track.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the super class should validate itself.  An object needs to enforce its own contract.  Any validation of C's values should be done in its own constructor.  Likewise, the subclass should validate itself.

```
public class A {
    private int x;

    public A(int x) {
        if (x < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x cannot be negative");
        this.x = x;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private String y;

    public B(int x, String y) {
        super(x);
        if (y == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("y cannot be null");
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to automatically call from A a method implemented in B, right at the end of B's constructor... right ?

Comment: No, A should never know that it's subclassed at all.  That code does not belong in B.  You'd be asking a class to be clairvoyant and predict the future: "Six months from now, Freddy will be subclassing me.  I'd better be ready to put that validation call from his class into my stuff."  Crazy.

Comment: A does not know B so it's impossible

Comment: But A could provide an abstract method... Which it seems we cannot call at the point I want.

Comment: Sorry, still wrong in every way.  Why do you insist on this?  Put the validation where it belongs and be done with it.

Comment: @duffymo I will accept you answer, but that does not mean that we should not think whether there are some other ways of doing things than we usually do. Any anyways, after all, your reply is the only that respects the conditions I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it'll "work".  But the question remains: How does A expect to know how it's extended in every case?  What if someone decides to extend A and not tell you?  What happens to your validation then?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of principle, C should not know about C1's properties, because C1 is a specialization of C.  However, what you can do is make an abstract validate() method in C, that must be implemented by C1.  Then, in C's constructor, you can call the abstract method.  Since, C1 will have to implement the validate(), it can then add it's property/field validation there.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the C1 validation will be called before setting the T property. This because, and I did mention, the super() call must be the 1st statement.

Comment: In that case, you can't automatically validate when the C constructor is called, correct?  So then you are left with letting C1 validate it's own properties that it is adding to the class hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think this will work. How should the base class validate the parameters if it doesn't know which there are? Is it such a big deal to do it in the extended class?

Comment: Maybe if you describe the actual scenario that you are trying to program for, we could help suggest a good pattern.  But as a general principle, you don't want C to know about C1. if C1 'is-a' C, then it must be a specialization.  If it is not a specialization, it is the same class.

Comment: @guitarflow yes, that is why the abstract method is forced to be implemented by the subclass.  Then, the subclass's validation for its properties is done in the subclass.

Comment: @guitarflow the subclass does its own validation, its just that the method that does it cannot be called at the end of subclasses' constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is against all OO principles, you could take advantage of Java's reflection property. Via reflection you can find out which methods and fields a class has. So you could pass the subclass object to the base class and the base class could check for all fields and validate them. If you do this at the end of the subclass constructor, you could let the validation method return a value to see if the values are valid or not.

I want to state that I don't think it's the right way to go but it should work

Comment: "Is not the right way" - yes, but it will work.  There's nothing in the language to forbid foolishness.

Comment: Eventually it will. I don't guarantee it will. It just came to my mind that if you call a method from within a constructor which you pass "this" to, I am not sure if this works as the object has eventually not yet been completely created. So this might be null. Try it out and get back here so we all know if it worked or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class C{
    Object x, y, z;
    public C(Object x, Object y, Object z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    public boolean validate(){ /**do stuff**/}
}

class D{
    public D(/**args**/){
        super(/**args**/);
        if(validate()){
            /**do stuff**//
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to push the validation to the base class, do it in an automatic manner.