# Design Pattern for TypeOf Subclass

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, design-patterns, reflection

I am working on a parser for a serial data protocol.  I have an overarching `Packet` class, a couple sub-classes such as `CommandPacket` and `StatusPacket`, and then a few sub-classes of each of those:

- Packet
- - CommandPacket
- - - CommandTypeA
- - - CommandTypeB
- - Status Packet
- - - StatusTypeA
- - - StatusTypeB

The `Packet` class has a static method for taking data off of a buffer, and if it represents a valid packet, returning a new instance of the `Packet` class, instantiated with the necessary data.

**Now, this is where my problem comes up.**  I would like to be able to return the **most specific** type of packet.  To facilitate this, I have created a static `.isValid()` method, which is overridden on the sub classes.  The idea is that I could loop through each type of specific packet (`CommandTypeA`, `CommandTypeB`, `StatusTypeA`, `StatusTypeB`, etc.) calling `.isValid()` until one of them returned `TRUE`.  At that point, I would return a new instance of that specific packet type.

While of course it is possible for me to create this method directly, how do I account for types of packets that are not added to my project yet?  I want someone to be able to extend my class in the future without having to modify the original `Packet` class.

I have considered utilizing reflection for this, but am avoiding it, since these methods would be called for each and every packet received, and must be efficient.

**Any thoughts on how I should re-work my design pattern?**

---

*While I don't think it is entirely relelvant to the discussion, I am doing this in VB.NET.  There is also a similar (but not quite the same) question posted here:  [Java - subclass validation design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226060/java-subclass-validation-design-pattern)*

Comment: How about this: Create a registry of validators, e.g. `class ValidatorsRegistry : Dictionary<Type,Action<Packet>> {}` and then registering validators per type, e.g. `validatorsMap.Add(typeof(CommandPacket), IsValidCommandPacket);`, and looping as your already do.

Comment: @AVIDeveloper, Thanks for the advice.  At what point would I add the types to this dictionary?  Ideally, it would be within the type classes themselves, but they won't be instantiated yet.  I suppose I should just create this when my base class is loaded?

Comment: That's where C++ static c'tors would be handy. But, anyway, you'll need to register them in some common Init() method of your assembly. Maybe there's a better way, but that's what comes to mind at this time of night.

Comment: Another location would be a static c'tor for an assembly's main class. This will make sure things are added in an early stage (this implies that your registry will have a static accessor, which goes pretty well with a Singleton pattern for example).

Comment: +1 @AVIDeveloper I'd like to suggest that the registry could be constructed using reflection. Just iterate the types in the assembly and add every subtype of Packet. Then additional packet types can be added just by adding the class. The reflection only happens once at startup so performance issues might not be relevant?

Comment: @MarkJ - Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for (it's like failing to remember the name of an actor). You nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and MarkJ's lead, here's a suggestion (which is eventually based on an interface instead of an attribute for stronger type checking):

```
public interface IPacketValidator
{
    bool IsPacketValid( Packet packet );
    Type PacketType { get; }
}

public class ValidatorsRegistry
{
    private List<IPacketValidator> m_validatorsList;

    private static ValidatorsRegistry m_Instance = new ValidatorsRegistry();
    public static ValidatorsRegistry Instance { get { return m_Instance; } }

    private ValidatorsRegistry()
    {
        InitValidatorsRegistry();
    }

    private void InitValidatorsRegistry()
    {
        m_validatorsList = new List<IPacketValidator>();

        Type iPacketValidatorType = typeof( IPacketValidator );

        foreach ( Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() )
        {
            foreach ( Type type in asm.GetTypes() )
            {
                if ( iPacketValidatorType.IsAssignableFrom( type ) && type != iPacketValidatorType )
                {
                    IPacketValidator validator = (IPacketValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    m_validatorsList.Add( validator );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Type GetSpecificPacketType(Packet packet)
    {
        Type packetType = typeof( Packet );
        foreach ( IPacketValidator validator in m_validatorsList )
        {
            if ( validator.IsPacketValid( packet ) )
            {
                packetType = validator.PacketType;
                break;
            }
        }

        return packetType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for an dependency injection container or MEF I would say.

But back to the question, so you need to have both a `Packet` with state and an ability to validate without setting this state. There are several options here, neither is perfect:

1. Have a one instance of each subclass as a template and ask each instance whether it can clone itself with the given data. Disadvantage: No static guarantees that template will not be passed around as an actual instance.
2. Move this logic to a separate `PacketFactory` and allow more than one factory (for extensibility).  Disadvantage: if the selection logic is tightly coupled with packet type, it creates two sources of truth.
3. Use static method as you currently do, and have a list of `Func<X, Packet>`, where Func will return `Packet` instance if `X` is valid or `null` if it is not. Disadvantage: no static guarantees this method is implemented.
4. (Just for the sake of completeness): same as 1, but create template bypassing the constructor, so that this kind of object will not be creatable in normal situation. Disadvantage: hack.

In all of these cases discovery can be done with either reflection-on-startup in custom case or with whatever extension mechanisms are provided by chosen DI framework.